# In XE7,TEdit.OnApplyStyleLookup is not in work

Tags: delphi, edit, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

1. Create a simple FireMonkey Mobile app.
2. Add a TEdit field to the form.
3. Assign OnApplyStyleLookup Event
4. Write the following code

   ```
   procedure TForm1.Edit1ApplyStyleLookup(Sender: TObject);
   var
     Obj: TFmxObject;
   begin
     Obj := Edit1.FindStyleResource('background');
     if Obj <> nil then
       ShowMessage('Obj is not nil')
     else
       ShowMessage('Obj is nil');
   end;
   ```

The code in the XE6 is running good, inside XE7 Obj is nil.
Excuse me, this is what reason, how to get to Obj?

The following code, access to the Obj is the same as the NIL value:

```
TMyEdit = class(TEdit)
protected
  procedure ApplyStyle;override;
...

procedure TMyEdit.ApplyStyle;
var
  Obj: TFmxObject;
begin
  inherited;
  Obj := Self.FindStyleResource('background');
  ...
end;
```

Comment: The use of TMemo, can be Obj not nil

Comment: `TEdit.FResourceLink` is `nil`. Lord knows why.

Comment: What is the ControlType property set to? If it's Platform you will be using a native edit control and, thus, no style. To change styles set it to Styled.

Comment: The two type is the same as the result

Comment: @Mike where can we find out about the ability to use native controls? Does that extend to Windows? FWIW the issue in the Q manifests for a default control on Windows which I believe is styled.

Comment: Who has a good solution?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan at the moment it's only for TEdit and TCalender on iOS - http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/FMX.Controls.Presentation.TPresentedControl.ControlType

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with C++Builder XE7. This is how I got around it. I created that function:

```
static Fmx::Types::TFmxObject* __fastcall FindStyle(
    Fmx::Types::TFmxObject* AFmxObject, const System::UnicodeString AStyleLookup)
{
    if(AFmxObject == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    Fmx::Types::TFmxObject* Result = NULL;
    const int LChildrenCount = AFmxObject->ChildrenCount;
    for(int i = 0; i < LChildrenCount; ++i)
    {
        if(AFmxObject->Children->Items[i]->StyleName == AStyleLookup)
        {
            Result = AFmxObject->Children->Items[i];
            break;
        }
        Result = FindStyle(AFmxObject->Children->Items[i], AStyleLookup);
        if(Result != NULL)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return Result;
}
```

Simply call the function like this:

```
#if __CODEGEARC__ < 0x0690
    Fmx::Types::TFmxObject* LStyleResource = LEdit->FindStyleResource("background");
#else
    Fmx::Types::TFmxObject* LStyleResource = FindStyle(LEdit, "background");
#endif
```

It's not that complicated so I guess it will be easy to code it for Delphi.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, I used the Delphi test is feasible

Comment: But this follows XE6 why there is so much different, is it XE7 BUG? I do not know whether the fix in XE7UP1